# Wrong text due to whitespace using python and sendmail

Tags: python, linux, email

I generated a file in following format with a python script on a linux server

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Server Information +++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Hostname                     :          ABC    
FQDN                         :          ABC.XYZ.com    
RHEL Release                 :          Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.8 Santiago    
Booted Kernel                :          2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64    
Top Kernel in Grub           :          2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64    
Vendor                       :          VMware, Inc.    
Model                        :          VMware Virtual Platform    
Uptime                       :          194 days        
Time                         :          14:58:41 CDT    
Boot Disk                    :          sda
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I am sending above text stored  in a file through sendmail with following command

```
mail -s "Subject" EMAILADDRESS  < Path to File
```

Text shown in Mail body isn't interpreting whitespace characters properly. For example, the text in mail:

```
Hostname          :         ABC    
FQDN         :        ABC.XYZ.att.com    
RHEL Release     :      Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
```

What needs to be done so that mail body interprets white space characters correctly? Anything needs to be done with character encoding?

For reference, lines are written in file as following :

```python
f.write('Hostname'.ljust(20) + ':'.center(20) + runCmd(['uname','-n']) + "\t")
```

Comment: A small nit... `FQDN : ABC.XYZ.com` is *not* a FQDN. A FQDN ends in a dot (`.`), and it denotes the top of the DNS tree. `localhost` is *not* a FQDN; while `localhost.` is a FQDN. `localhost.localdomain` is *not* a FQDN; while `localhost.localdomain.` is a FQDN. Also see W. Richard Stevens' [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume 1](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201633469).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.